# Restangular and UI-Bootstrap first page appears blank

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, restangular

I am currently getting to grips with Restangular and seem to be making some headway. I have opted to use the UI-Bootstrap for the ease of use, as I am use to working with bootstrap before.

My current issue is that I have pagination working for my controller, however the results do not appear when you first visit the page. If I visit the second page and then go back to the first page the results are there as expected. If I then choose to reload the page in anyway the results on the first page do not appear.

My code is as follows:

```
app.controller('BillsListCtrl', function ($scope, BillRepository) {
  $scope.filteredBills = [],
  $scope.currentPage = 1,
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

  $scope.bills = BillRepository.getList();

  $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
      end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

    $scope.filteredBills = $scope.bills.slice(begin, end);
  });

  console.log($scope.filteredBills);

});
```

The Repository:

```
app.factory('AbstractRepository', [

  function () {

    function AbstractRepository(restangular, route) {
      this.restangular = restangular;
      this.route = route;
    }

    AbstractRepository.prototype = {
      getList: function (params) {
        return this.restangular.all(this.route).getList(params).$object;
      },
      get: function (id) {
        return this.restangular.one(this.route, id).get();
      },
      getView: function (id) {
        return this.restangular.one(this.route, id).one(this.route + 'view').get();
      },
      update: function (updatedResource) {
        return updatedResource.put().$object;
      },
      create: function (newResource) {
        return this.restangular.all(this.route).post(newResource);
      },
      remove: function (object) {
        return this.restangular.one(this.route, object.id).remove();
      }
    };

    AbstractRepository.extend = function (repository) {
      repository.prototype = Object.create(AbstractRepository.prototype);
      repository.prototype.constructor = repository;
    };

    return AbstractRepository;
  }
]);
```

Setting up the BillRepository:

```
app.factory('BillRepository', ['Restangular', 'AbstractRepository',
  function (restangular, AbstractRepository) {

    function BillRepository() {
      AbstractRepository.call(this, restangular, 'bills');
    }

    AbstractRepository.extend(BillRepository);
    return new BillRepository();
  }
]);
```

Any light you can shed on this issue would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes to @ErikAGriffin for his help with this.

I made a change in my repository and removed the `$object` as shown below:

```
getList: function (params) {
    return this.restangular.all(this.route).getList(params);
},
```

Then my controller changed to the following:

```
app.controller('BillsListCtrl', function ($scope, BillRepository) {
    $scope.filteredBills = [],
    $scope.currentPage = 1,
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

    $scope.bills = BillRepository.getList().$object;

    BillRepository.getList().then(function(data){
        $scope.filteredBills = data.slice(0, $scope.itemsPerPage);
    });

    $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
         end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredBills = $scope.bills.slice(begin, end);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$scope.filteredBills` is what's being displayed on the page, you're only populating that variable when the currentPage variable is changed.  When your code runs for the first time, you set the variable and then set the watch on it, so it doesn't change and filteredBills does not get set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so how would I get the watch to be applied on the load, through `$scope.init` or some other method?

Comment: You can just put it outside of any watch or other function and it will run only once just like when you're setting `$scope.bills` As in right after, put something like `$scope.filteredBills = $scope.bills.slice(0,10)`.  Also, unless you're actually using `$scope.bills` in your view I would just make bills a local `var`.

Comment: When running `$scope.filteredBills = $scope.bills.slice(0,10)` the first time, all that is returned is an empty array. The console on Chrome returns `[]`.

Comment: Well I don't know what `BillRepository` is, but most likely you will need to use a promise or a callback to set the filteredBills only after the `getList()` has resolved.  I think you could use `.then(function(){$scope.filteredBills = etc..})`

Comment: Thanks @ErikAGriffin, managed to get it working with your help.